# character to bullet conversion in c#

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, ms-office, powerpoint

Currently i am developing a pptx viewer which involves parsing the pptx files which is stored as zipped xml files with relationship between the xml files.

Special bullets used in presentation sheets such as [image: The image denotes a bullet followed by text- Title]. Such bullets will be stored as characters in xml files. The bullet shown in the image is stored as character "q". Parsing the Xml we get the data which will be represented as "q" again

Is there any method or library which helps in conversion of the character used to represent the bullet to the actual bullet as shown in the image to be drawn on to the WinForm using C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be seeing something like this in the XML:

```
<a:buFont typeface="Wingdings" pitchFamily="2" charset="2"/><a:buChar char="q"/>
```

In other words, the bullet is the character in the Wingdings font that resides at the position (113) that q would occupy in a "normal" font.

Display a q in Wingdings and you'll get the box bullet.

Comment: how to do the conversion for numbered or alphanumeric type bullets.
Example:

`<a:buFont typeface="+mj-lt"/>
<a:buAutoNum type="alphaLcParenR"/>`

Comment: or is there a method to convert an integer value to any of the ST_TextAutonumberScheme enumeration types? Ex : An integer 2 to type alphaLcParenBoth (b) .

Comment: I suspect you'd have to build your own function to convert integer (long in VBA) values to the strings you need for XML.  It's simple enough to get the values to use:  Start PPT, ALT+F11 to open the IDE, press F2 for the object browser and search for ppNumberedBulletStyle and MsoNumberedBulletStyle